# retreive data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to retrieve data from MySQL that recorded by the same person that had logged in before?
She records / saves her daily activities.
The table is as follow:

STUDENT

```
stu_id  stu_name    stu_pass
101     sara        1234  
102     bob         1133
```

---

ACTIVITY

```
act_id  stu_id  act_name
1       101      badminton
2       101      tennis
3       102      volleyball 
4       101      hockey
5       102      football
```

How to list the activity that only done by Sara (stu_id: 101)?

Comment: "SELECT act_name FROM ACTIVITY WHERE stu_id=101" ?

Comment: "that recorded by the same person that had logged in before?"... this makes me think the answer is more complicated, but you need to supply the data, code, etc before we can answer it.

Comment: Agree with downvote.  Inadequate research ... since this is (perhaps) such basic SQL

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.stu_name, b.act_name 
FROM student a INNER JOIN activity b on a.stu_id = b.act_id 
WHERE  a.stu_id = 101
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `act_name` 
FROM `activity`
WHERE `stu_id` IN (SELECT `stu_id` WHERE `stu_name` = 'sara')
```

However, I'd imagine that `stu_id` is a primary, and indexed, so you wouldn't need that nested query, and just query it directly. Therefore making it;

```
SELECT `act_name` 
FROM `activity`
WHERE `stu_id` = 101
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the stu_id of the loged in person

After that you can (use PDO to replace :stu_id with the logged in users stu_id):

```
SELECT * FROM ACTIVITY WHERE stu_id = :stu_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `STUDENT` t1 
JOIN `ACTIVITY` t2 ON t1.stu_id = t2.stu_id  
WHERE t1.stu_id = 101;
```